# How to smooth area shape="poly" curves?

Tags: imagemap

I am using image maps to provide the input for mouse over shading, nothing fancy here, but I've created polygons that have some sharp edges I'd prefer to see smoothed away.

At the same time I'd like to reduce the overall number of points by removing anything that would lie on a straight line, eg if points a, b and c fall on a straight line, remove point b.

Does anyone know of such an algorithm, preferably implemented in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

We went down this path on a project once -- there is no other option than a whole mess of points.  But from testing there doesn't seem to be any real issue with lots of points in the poly method and the size of the text (with all the numeric points) is nominal in the overall scope of HTML and supporting files.

So, as ugly as it looks in raw code, I recommend you just go ahead with the large number of points.

Comment: This is uesful for me from the point of view of the number of points, but a lot of my corners are still blockish looking.  I can try to manually add more points, especially if I can find the particular co-ordinates that form the sharp corner, so that issue is still very much an issue.

Comment: There are a number of online tools for image map generators and built in tools in Adobe and other web editing tools.  Most of these have some sort of zoom and edit tool, but those tools are very much a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'll do if I don't find an alternative.  I know there are algorithms for doing this using tangents to the curve to check for "sharp" features.  I have enough image maps to make it worth writing a function for if it's not absurd to implement.